# How to post image and other parameters as form data via REST api with Swift URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rest

I need to upload image with some other values via REST api (form data) post method. I have fetched the image from gallery by the code below.

```
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showImagePicker.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Choose your file")
            }
            image?.resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
            ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image in
                self.image = Image(uiImage: image)
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to send other values as like "studentPaymentTypeId" with this API call. Being new in SwifUI I am confused how SwiftUI handles multipart REST API call. I have attached postman screenshot of my working API which I want to implement.

[image]

Now, how can I send the image file with all other parameters over REST api post method to server?

I tried the code below but not working!

```
func uploadReceipt(image: UIImage) {
        
        let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "login_token")
        
        
        // create post request

        
        guard let url = URL(string: "my url") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        

        // generate boundary string using a unique per-app string
        let boundary = UUID().uuidString

        let session = URLSession.shared

        // Set the URLRequest to POST and to the specified URL
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            //"Content-Type": "application/json",
            //"Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+token!
        ]

        // Set Content-Type Header to multipart/form-data, this is equivalent to submitting form data with file upload in a web browser
        // And the boundary is also set here
        urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var data = Data()

        // Add the image data to the raw http request data
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; studentPaymentTypeId=\"\(1)\";classTermId=\"\(1)\";sessionId=\"\(1)\"; attachmentFile=\"\(imageToSent!)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
       
        data.append(image.pngData()!)

        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

        // Send a POST request to the URL, with the data we created earlier
        session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: data, completionHandler: { responseData, response, error in
            if error == nil {
                let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: .allowFragments)
                if let json = jsonData as? [String: Any] {
                    print(json)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) I managed to upload Multipart Form Data.

Here is the code below :

```
import Alamofire
```

.
.
.

```
func uploadReceipt(){
        
        
        let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "login_token")
        
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization("Bearer "+token!),
            .accept("application/json")
            
        ]
        
        
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            
            
            multipartFormData.append(imageToSent!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!, withName: "attachmentFile", fileName: "someFile.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            multipartFormData.append("1".data(using: .utf8)!, withName :"studentPaymentTypeId")
            multipartFormData.append("1".data(using: .utf8)!, withName :"classTermId")
            multipartFormData.append("1".data(using: .utf8)!, withName :"sessionId")
            
        }, to: "https://lms.learnerscafe.com/api/payment", method: .post, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                
                print("Validation Successful)")
                
                
            case .failure(let error):
                
                print(error)
                
                
            }
            
           
        }
        
    }
```